# AWS RDS backups are incremental or differential?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In the AWS RDS documentation, it is written that automatic daily backups are performed. But it is not specified whether it is incremental or differential.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html

Can you please tell the type of backup AWS performs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most meaningful answer is "neither."

RDS snapshots are full backups... but they are initially created incrementally.

RDS snapshots are EBS snapshots of the underlying block storage device(s).

> Amazon RDS creates a storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance and not just individual databases.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html

Logically, each snapshot is a standalone snapshot.  You can delete older ones, and still successfully restore newer ones.  You can delete all but one, and still restore that one, no matter which one.

They are actually created as incremental snapshots, with only the blocks that differ from the previous snapshot being captured from the disk and stored¹... so a snapshot completes much faster when a smaller amount of change has occurred since the prior snapshot... but the captured data is not "in" a specific snapshot -- each snapshot contains pointers to all of the snapshot data blocks that are required to reconstruct it -- so if a newer snapshot depends on data that was originally captured in an older snapshot, that's fine: deleting the older snapshot does not cause the data to actually be discarded, as long as the data is still referenced by at least one snapshot.

> When you delete a snapshot, only the data referenced exclusively by that snapshot is removed. Deleting previous snapshots of a volume does not affect your ability to restore volumes from later snapshots of that volume.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-deleting-snapshot.html

---

¹ *only the blocks that differ* is possible because the EBS infrastructure knows which blocks on your volume have remained untouched since the previous snapshot that is still being stored.  When RDS asks EBS to snapshot the underlying storage volume, EBS only reads the blocks that have been touched.  How, exactly, this works isn't documented but there's clear evidence of this sort of optimization in the short amount of time needed for taking snapshots when very little data has changed, compared to longer times when many changes have occurred.

Comment: How does it impact the cost for backup storage?
Let say having two snapshots of 5G:
- `snapshot-1`
- `snapshot-2`

Will Amazon will charge for storage backup of 10G or only 5GB. I am curious about that..

Comment: I would like to answer for my own question. As the rds internally using incremental back-up so It only charge for underlying data storage being used for all snapshots. If the second backup does not contain any additional changes since last one so no additional data change captures then no another storage charged

Comment: That doest seem to be whats the doc is saying here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html "The first snapshot of a DB instance contains the data for the full DB instance. Subsequent snapshots of the same DB instance are incremental, which means that only the data that has changed after your most recent snapshot is saved."

Comment: @zehawk that isn't different than what I said.  Logically each backup is standalone, even though the process for creating them is incremental. The blocks of data referenced by each snapshot are tracked, allowing you to delete older snapshots without losing the ability to restore newer snapshots, because the data isn't actually stored "in" the snapshots at all.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the detailed explanation on RDS. Can I ask you how amazon aurora is behaving in this context? As amazon aurora doesn't have any associated EBS volumes to each instances (reader or writer), how is the snapshot-ing of "cluster volume" takes place? The comparison between these two engines making me so doubtful.

Comment: @KishorUnnikrishnan *"Aurora backups are continuous and incremental so you can quickly restore to any point within the backup retention period."* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Backups.html The underlying mechanisms aren't disclosed, but the docs imply that Aurora seems to be saving an actual log of disk changes over the course of the retention period.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS backup type is an incremental backup, the first backup always would be a full backup and rest of backups would be incremental. Suppose your RDS backup retention period is seven days so in case if we need to rewind our db exactly back to 1 day, then first full backup and last five subsequent will be applied.

Comment: can u give a document supporting that RDS backup is incremental?

Comment: Right here: The first snapshot of a DB instance contains the data for the full DB instance. Subsequent snapshots of the same DB instance are incremental, which means that only the data that has changed after your most recent snapshot is saved. from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html. Though its highly confusing...

Answer (score 0):

It is a Full snapshot of EBS.
It is neither an incremental nor differential backup.

It is a full backup. and whenever we need to restore from previous snapshots, just select the date and COMPLETE RDS is replicated. and no need to process any other backup.

AWS Says "Turned on by default, the automated backup feature of Amazon RDS will backup your databases and transaction logs. Amazon RDS automatically creates a storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance and not just individual databases. "
Refer: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/backup/